# I want to remove the directory using ansible

Tags: ansible

I want to use a variable to remove a directory if it is true.
(remove_test: false, remove not test directory)

```
vars:
 remove_test: true

- name: "remove test directory"
  file: path=/test state=absent
  when: remove_test
```

Comment: And what happens when you execute your playbook? Do you get an error message?

Comment: You told us what you want, and IMO showed little interest in making your post look good (formatting codeblocks: select the lines press `{}`). You also don't seem to have read the [tour] which would have explained that this is Q&A site, and how to use this site: an interrogative sentence (and not something useless like "Can anyone help?") is almost always mandatory. You added the tag [tag:yaml] (which brought me here), but you might as well have use [tag:ascii] that would be as irrelevant.

Answer (score -1):

basic test codes

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - name: "remove test directory"
      vars:
        remove_test: true
      file: path=/test state=absent
      when: remove_test
```

and you can set remove_test a variable, transfer value from outer

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. But it doesn't work. I have defined the hosts in the hosts file.                                                       
  tasks:
    - name: "remove test directory"
      vars:
        remove_test: true
      file: path=/test state=absent
      when: remove_test     The execution command is "ansible-playbook -K playbook.yml"                ERROR! The tasks/main.yml file for role 'basic' must contain a list of tasks tasks:
^ here

Comment: playbook.yml is - hosts: all
  become: true
  become_user: abc
  roles:
  - basic

Comment: ansible-playbook -K playbook.yml --extra-vars remove_test=true is same error.. Did something wrong??

Comment: first， I have tested the code I wrote, and it worked! second, you need to paste your error and code properlly here,and I will see it

Comment: Error message is ERROR! The tasks/main.yml file for role 'basic' must contain a list of tasks

The error appears to have been in '/ansible/roles/basic/tasks/main.yml': line 1, column 1, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:


tasks:
^ here

Comment: @joy0120 please learn to use the appropriate formatting when seeking for help. Your previous comments are incomprehensible.